# Pandas: How can I add new rows of data based on conditional statements?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use conditional statements to append rows of data to columns in Pandas. For an example, I have 2 DataFrames: **Average Weekly Scores** and **Grade For Week**. Both of these have columns for student names and every week, starting from week1 onwards. I want to take the average score from the week of each student and insert a grade for the week in the **Grade For Week** DataFrame.

Average Weekly Scores:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [
        {"Student": "Samantha", "AVG WK A": 104, "AVG WK B": 114},
        {"Student": "Billy", "AVG WK A": 70, "AVG WK B": 92},
    ],
)

print(df)
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
|    | Student   |   AVG WK A |   AVG WK B |
|----+-----------+------------+------------|
|  0 | Samantha  |        104 |        114 |
|  1 | Billy     |         70 |         92 |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Grade For Week (what I want to happen):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [
        {"Student": "Samantha", "Week A": "A", "Week B": "A+"},
        {"Student": "Billy", "Week A": "C-", "Week B": "A"},
    ],
)

print(df)
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|    | Student   | Week A   | Week B   |
|----+-----------+----------+----------|
|  0 | Samantha  | A        | A+       |
|  1 | Billy     | C-       | A        |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Essentially, I have a DataFrame with values that I will use for my conditional statements in my second DataFrame. Scores at or over 110 will be an A+, Scores < 110 but > 91 will be A's and anything less than 91 is a C-. I want to create a for loop that will check every column's row of data from the **Average Weekly Scores** DataFrame and give the appropriate grade to the column rows in the **Grade For Week** DataFrame.

The closest I got to was with the `df.loc[len(df)]` function. But obviously it added the same values for all the columns like this:

Grade For Week (**not** what I want to happen):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [
        {"Student": "Samantha", "Week A": "A", "Week B": "A"},
        {"Student": "Billy", "Week A": "C-", "Week B": "C-"},
    ],
)

print(df)
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|    | Student   | Week A   | Week B   |
|----+-----------+----------+----------|
|  0 | Samantha  | A        | A        |
|  1 | Billy     | C-       | C-       |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
```

I have been at this for a couple of days now and I could really use some help! Thank you and if you have any other questions please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets use `np.select` to assign the grades based on the range conditions

```
scores = df.set_index('Student')
scores.columns = scores.columns.str.replace('AVG WK', 'Week')

scores[:] = np.select(
    condlist=[scores >= 110, (scores < 110) & (scores > 91)], 
    choicelist=['A+', 'A'], default='C-'
)

scores = scores.reset_index()
```

Result

| Student | Week A | Week B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Samantha | A | A+ |
| Billy | C- | A |

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, I am getting a depreciated warning when I use this method. Is there away to get around that?

Comment: I don't see a reason for warning can you please share the exact warning message?

Comment: Here is what I get:
DeprecationWarning:

In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. To retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`

Comment: Hmm. what is `i` and `newvals`?

Comment: I'm not sure, they are not any variables that I am using in any of my codes. I think it's the syntax of the newer versions but I do not know what I should change to fix the error.

Comment: np! Can you let me know your pandas version?

Comment: Also can you try `scores[scores.columns]` instead of `scores[:]`

Comment: My pandas version: 1.5.3

Comment: That's strange I'm using the same pandas version and i don't get any warning.

Comment: I changed scores[:] to scores[scores.columns] and it ended up working. Thank you for all your help!